# Column manipulations in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning to work with Apache Spark (Scala) and still figuring out how things work out here

I am trying to achieve a simple task of

1. Finding max of column
2. Subtract each value of the column from this max and create a new column

The code I am using is

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val training = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (10),
  (13),
  (14),
  (21)
)).toDF("Values")

val training_max = training.withColumn("Val_Max",training.groupBy().agg(max("Values"))
val training_max_sub = training_max.withColumn("Subs",training_max.groupBy().agg(col("Val_Max")-col("Values) ))
```

However I am getting a lot of errors. I am more or less fluent in R and had I been doing the same task my code would have been:

```
library(dplyr)
new_data <- training %>%
    mutate(Subs= max(Values) - Values)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using window functions. You'll need a `HiveContext` to use them

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val training = sc.parallelize(Seq(10,13,14,21)).toDF("values")

training.withColumn("subs", 
   max($"values").over(Window.partitionBy()) - $"values").show
```

Which produces the expected output :

```
+------+----+
|values|subs|
+------+----+
|    10|  11|
|    13|   8|
|    14|   7|
|    21|   0|
+------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was perfect